# How to get current WiFi signal strength?

Tags: wifi, nodemcu

I have a LCD display where in I'm displaying a WiFi signal logo. I want to reduce the number of bars on the logo, indicating that the signal strength is dropping. I got the reducing bars on the LCD completed, I still have to find out the actual signal strength.

How do I find the signal strength of the connected network with ESP8266 based NodeMCU?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use [`WiFi.RSSI()`](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/station-class.html#rssi):

> ## RSSI
>
> Return the signal strength of Wi-Fi network, that is formally called Received Signal Strength Indication (RSSI).
>
> ```
> WiFi.RSSI()
> ```
>
> Signal strength value is provided in dBm. The type of returned value is int32_t.
>
> Example code:
>
> ```
> Serial.printf("RSSI: %d dBm\n", WiFi.RSSI());
> ```
>
> Example output:
>
> ```
> RSSI: -68 dBm
> ```